# Webdriver how to get the page has been opened

Tags: python, webdriver

```
driver = webdriver.chrome()

driver.get(url)
```

Webdriver are used to open a web page.

But if I turn it.
First open a web page, and then use webdriver access source, feasible? ??

（The first time to come here to ask questions, did not find the forum on python.
I do not know right here!）

Comment: You want to open a browser **as an independent process**, and then access this process via Python's webdriver (i.e., from a different process)?

Comment: If you mean you want to access the page's source from webdriver, then yes, it is possible through `driver.page_source`.

Comment: Under normal circumstances is webdriver open the browser, and then open the page in the access source。。

Now I want to do that.
For example: first open manually with firefox http://stackoverflow.com/
Then use python's webdriver to get its source code

Answer (score 0):

For example:

first open manually with firefox stackoverflow.com

Then use python's webdriver to get its source code

Is there a way?
(My English is not good, automatic translation)